# How to define a cursor, when we have a common column between two tables without giving alias

Tags: plsql, cursor

I have 4 tables: T1,T2,T3 and T4. All of them have more than 50 columns.There are few columns which are common between above 4 tables. Lets say C1 is present in all 4 tables. There are few more columns which are common between above multiple tables.
Now if i decalre a cursor CUR1 as:

```
cursor CUR1 as select * from T1,T2,T3,T4 where <join conditions for 4 tables>;
```

I am gettign error while fetching the data due to ambiguity of common column C1.
Is it possible to avoid the error without listing each and every column names and their alias?
Somehow can i append the any idicator for all the column of table without specifying alias for every columns?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, as far as I can tell. However, if you frequently use the same `FROM ... WHERE` clause, you could create a **view** (therefore, do it once, specifying every single column - with its alias - in order to avoid the error) and then use the view in your `SELECT` statements.